# android Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 even with Multidex.jar

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-appcompat

In my application i have added appcompat-v7 lib project and google-play-services(need maps and drive api) lib project. And some more libraries which are necessary to execute my menu functions in application.

Used libraries:

- google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-api-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-api-services-drive-v2-rev65-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-http-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-http-client-gson-1.14.1-beta.jar
- google-oauth-client-1.14.1-beta.jar
- gson-2.1.jar
- itextpdf-5.5.3.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar
- jackson-core-2.4.1.jar
- jackson-databind-2.4.1.jar
- jsr305-1.3.9.jar
- jxl.jar
- opencsv-2.4.jar
- simple-xml-2.7.1.jar
- universal-image-loader-1.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

While launching getting error as "Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536"

Note: I have tried with adding Multidex.jar in libs for pre-lollipop devices, but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be because of the 65K Reference Limit when it comes to methods in libraries. Are you using the entire Google Play Services library or the compact version which has seperated its functions based on your needs:

Look at Table 1 at https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

This way for maps and drive, you would have three libraries:

- Google Play Services core
- Google Play Services Map
- Google Play Services Drive

And not have to worry about having ones you don't need like Google Fit or Google Wallet

Note: If you include a library without having Google Play Service core included, it will automatically be included, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks, i have added the entire Google Play Services library. Will try with the specific libs..